# Печать чека при помощи usb-библиотеки на node.js

Tags: node.js, npm, usb, принтер

Пытаюсь напечатать чек с помощью [библиотеки](https://www.npmjs.com/package/usb),
проблема возникает в том, что текст пишется, но чек не вылезает, то есть не происходит остановка печати. Как быть?

Устройство печати: Термопринтер Nippon NP-F309.

Так я на чек вывожу информацию:

```
outEndpoint.transfer('Hello, World', (error) => {
  console.log('outEndpoint.transfer', error);
})
```

но выдача чека не происходит.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В итоге пришли к такому решению на данный момент:

1. Подключаем библиотеку escpos.
2. Там есть метод printer.cut(), который обрезает чек, но на мой принтер опять же не подействовал. Пришлось лезть в исходники, в них 
   есть команды отправляемые на принтер. Вижу, что PAPER_FULL_CUT: '\x1d\x56\x00', а для моего принтера нужна команда '\x1b\x69'.
3. Меняю метод у себя на сервере таким образом:

> ```
> printer.cut = function (part, feed) {
>     this.feed(feed || 3);
>     this.buffer.write('\x1b\x69');
>     return this;
>   }
> ```

Теперь чек обрезается.

Но вообще все можно сделать одной библиотекой - https://www.npmjs.com/package/usb.

Comment: Добрый день. Можешь предоставить полный код чтобы распечатать с чек принтер плиз?